# Running a foreach loop within a Curl function

Tags: php, curl

I need to run a foreach loop within a curl command but can't quite get the syntax right. I've parsed other variables into it fine but it's just formatting my array to fit.

```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
      \"order\": {
        \"channel_id\": $channel_id,
        \"customer_id\": $customer_id,
        \"deliver_to_id\": $deliver_to_id,
        \"delivery_method_id\": $delivery_method_id,
        \"line_items_attributes\": [
          {
            \"sellable_id\": 39236017,
            \"price_per_unit\": \"1.000\",
            \"quantity\": \"10\"
          }
        ],
      }
    }");
```

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39235995
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 2.81
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39235995
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 2.81
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39236029
                    [quantity] => 0
                    [price] => 2.952
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39236015
                    [quantity] => 0
                    [price] => 3.333
                )

        )

)
```

I need to push my array into this part specifically:

```
\"sellable_id\": 39236017,
\"price_per_unit\": \"1.000\",
\"quantity\": \"10\"
```

This is my attempt but this is causing all kinds of issues, where am I going wrong?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
  \"order\": {
    \"channel_id\": $channel_id,
    \"customer_id\": $customer_id,
    \"deliver_to_id\": $deliver_to_id,
    \"delivery_method_id\": $delivery_method_id,
    \"line_items_attributes\": [
      {
        foreach($parcels[0] as $item){
          \"sellable_id\": $item['id'],
          \"price_per_unit\": $item['price'],
          \"quantity\": $item['quantity'],
        }
      }
    ],
  }
}");
```

---

Slight addition, what if the array was this and I didn't target it with `foreach($parcels[0] as $item) {` but it was `foreach($parcels as $item) {` instead?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39235995
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 2.46
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39236017
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 2.75
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39236029
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 2.58
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just put PHP code in string and expect it to be executed. You must transform your array, and then pass to cUrl:

```
$order = [
  "order" => [
    "channel_id" => $channel_id,
    "customer_id" => $customer_id,
    "deliver_to_id" => $deliver_to_id,
    "delivery_method_id" => $delivery_method_id,
    "line_items_attributes" => [
      [
        "sellable_id": 39236017,
        "price_per_unit": "1.000",
        "quantity": "10"
      ]
    ],
  ]
];

foreach($parcels[0] as $item) {
    $order['order']['line_items_attributes'][] = [
        "sellable_id" => $item['id'],
        "price_per_unit" => $item['price'],
        "quantity" => $item['quantity'],
    ];      
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($order));
```

Comment: Also adding a note here for Rob: By using `json_encode` you ensure all fields and data are properly escaped and valid json. Avoid trying to 'build the string yourself'. You will just create more headaches for yourself.

Comment: @Justinas Thanks that makes sense, it's working now!

Comment: @IncredibleHat Thanks for the info too, helps explain things a bit on something I'm terrible at!!

Comment: @Justinas I've just hit upon another setup, I've updated my question, how would I incorporate that style of array? Instead of doing `$parcels[0]` in the foreach?

Comment: @IncredibleHat I'm not sure if you can help with the additional question above? You grasped everything quickly.

Comment: @Rob Use double foreach.